# Windows 11 context menu appearance

Tags: context-menu, windows-11-v22h2

I very recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 Pro, Version 22H2, OS build 2621.2361.

I have noticed that context (right click) menus in File Explorer have an odd look, with lines separating the items. Is this normal, and is it possible to make the menus look more like I am used to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not normal. 3 machines here; 2 at 22621.2361 Production and 1 Insider.

None of these machines show lines in the Context Menu. I have been using Windows 11 for 2 years now and context has always looked fine.

Try the simplest initial repair (DISM and SFC).

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup /Resetbase
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Please let us know about this.  The next repair is a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

[Microsoft MCL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11)

While this does clearly look to be a Windows OS issue, you might also update your video driver just to be sure.

Comment: Also look to any add-ons to the OS you might have installed under Win 10 that are not totally v. 11 compatible that might cause that effect.

Comment: Based on your answer you should try a Windows Repair Install as suggested instead of relying upon a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

Some progress. I tried the 5 steps suggested by John, and there was no change. Then I read DrMoishe Pippik's comment and discovered that I had made a 'tweak' in Windows 11 using Winaero Tweaker. Specifically, I had checked 'Enable classic full context menus'. After I unchecked this, and restarted Explorer, the context menus were how they should be. However, when I click 'Show more options' I get a full menu, but the strange bar separator style is back.

[image]

Comment: You should get +1 for the cat pictures.

Comment: FINAL UPDATE - completely cured by changing Windows theme.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, why not edit the answer, and add the name of the theme causing the issue? And giving the system a CAT scan was a good idea ;-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - it was a highly customized Windows10 default theme I had monkeyed with on Windows 10 over 18 months prior to upgrading to Windows 11, since I bought the PC.